# PHP Mailer Session Problem

Tags: php, session, mailer

We are trying to implement a mailer with an attachment upload option.

It's working great on two of the servers I've uploaded it to.

However, it does not seem to work on my localhost wamp server or even on a different server:
http://203.76.126.68/mailer/

Why am I seeing session values inside the text boxes?
Can anyone point out what seems to be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short Open Tags might be turned off. The easiest way to fix this is to just do a find and replace and change `<?=` into `<?php echo`.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

You can also turn it on (might be possible in .htaccess) in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Check if that script is actually processed by PHP.

If it is process by the PHP CGI binary, make sure `short_open_tag` is set to **On**. Those `<?= ... ?>` thingies only work with `short_open_tag` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

you have shorttags off that's why you have to set it on in php ini or i think you can use the wamp menu and then setting and then turn on shorttags